# Best strategy for finding tasks with unobserved exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Suppose I have the following code:

```
private static void Run()
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Unobserved task exception!"); };

    try
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}

private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    var task1 = ThrowAsync();
    var task2 = ThrowAsync();

    await task1;
    await task2;
}

private static async Task ThrowAsync()
{
    throw new Exception("Test exception");
}
```

This code outputs `Unobserved task exception!` because the exception in `task2` is not observed.

My question is the following: is there any way to programmatically determine which task had an unobserved exception? For example, I want to get a stack trace for a method which invoked a task or something like this:

```
Unobserved exception: task2 in RunAsync()
```

Sadly, exception stack trace is not enough. The code above is just a demonstration, in a real-world application I sometimes have unobserved task exceptions with a stack trace like this:

```
System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.get_CurrentModuleContainer()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. Do you really need to know the actual `_Task_` object within which the exception was thrown? Or is it sufficient to get a more detailed stack trace? I don't think you can do the former; at least I'm not aware of anything in the `UnobservedTaskException` event that would provide this. But on the other hand, if all you want is more detail, you should be able to look at `AggregateException.InnerExceptions` to see the actual exceptions. Please improve the question with a more precise description of what information you want to get that you're not getting.

Comment: I think the question just means he (and I) just want to find where in our code the problem actually is. I may have hundreds or thousands of tasks by now, and somewhere I have `var t = GetSomethingAsync();` and I have no idea where

Answer (score 2):

One would be able to tell which Task instance had its exception unobserved. That would be `task2` under the second `await`

```
await task1;
await task2;
```

because the first `await` "observes" the result of `task1`.

Then if the event handler is modified to presenting the actual Task exception that `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` provides

```
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += delegate(object o, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs ea)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Unobserved task exception! {ea.Exception.ToString()}");
    };
```

then the failing region of the Task code can be tracked down by observing the exception's stack trace:

```
Unobserved task exception!
System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. (Test exception)
---> System.Exception: Test exception
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.ThrowAsync() in C:\Users\sergepavlov\Desktop\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 42
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Test exception
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.ThrowAsync() in C:\Users\sergepavlov\Desktop\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 42
<---
```

Hope that makes sense.